# Unable to delete own answer on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I asked a question and accidentally did an answer instead of a comment on an existing answer. I do not get the option to delete that answer from the app. I can only flag it.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-N910V
- OS Version: 5.0.1

I was not trying to vote for deletion. I was trying to delete my own answer which is a process that doesn't need a voting queue. It is not a duplicate of the vote for removal question.

Comment: Yes, however you can't see that answer when you're submitting a bug report. Which is just another limitation of the application. Also because of this issue I can't delete this question from the application. I'm about 10 miles from my desk.  I would suggest that both of these failures are result of using the META site to handle bug reports rather than a standard bug report solution.

Comment: Sure, can't disagree with any of that.

Comment: Internally, you as the author deleting your own post is *still* considered a vote to delete, with the exception that your vote is binding as the author. In fact, if you were to open up the timeline of a self-deleted question in a Web browser, the deletion would still be annotated as "via Vote", the same way as deletions by high-rep users voting to delete or a moderator deleting. So yes, it is still a duplicate of that question. Unfortunately, since you posted this question, the apps are no longer supported, and new builds are no longer being released for them.